# Hold reference to object for future method calls or fetch the object every time in long methods

Tags: java, garbage-collection

```
class A {
    void method1() {
        B b = new B();
        C c = new C();

        // Option 1
        List<Object> cachedObject = b.method1();
        c.method1(cachedObject);
        c.method2(cachedObject);

        // Option 2
        c.method1(b.method1());
        c.method2(b.method1());
    }
}

class B {
     List<Object> method1() {
     }
}

class C {
     void method1(List<Object> a) {
     }

     void method2(List<Object> a) {
     }
}
```

In option 2, does the argument to c.method1() be available for garbage collection after it returns turn out to be better compared to option 1 where we cache the object and use it in both method calls, c.method1() and c.method2() considering there are time consuming operations happening between c.method1() and c.method2() calls and hence the cached object is still referenced during that time and not available for garbage collection.

From memory utilization perspective, which option would work out better considering the object returned by b.method1() is huge(500MB+) ?

Comment: One thing is for sure, garbage collection does not happen because of *time consuming operations*.. it relies on the type of reference of the objects hold.

Comment: With such a generic question the answer is pretty much "it depends". One could conjure up scenarios where either is better according to one performance metric or another.

Answer (score 0):

There's a fine line to be walked here between Memory Utilization & Performance. The right answer really depends on your scenario. Here are some questions I would ask...

- What are your memory constraints? Could keeping this object cause your JVM to run out of Heap Space?
- What are your performance requirements? Does this object take a while to create and would recreating it slow down your application to an unacceptable degree?
- Garbage Collection is never guaranteed so what are the risks that you would have two of these object in memory at the same time?
- How many times/places do you need to use this object? Will it be passed around on separate threads and used asynchronously or will there be a large gap between uses?

One solution I would offer is to look at Java's `WeakReference` class. This class allows you to maintain a weak refernce to an object that does not prevent garbage collection. Whenever you want to use it, you would do a null check and if it was garbage collected, you can recreate it. This is usefull when you absolutely don't want multiple instances of your large object in memory since the weak reference will only be null once the old reference was garbage collected.

Comment: We hit a problem in production when we were using Option 2. The creation of the object was time consuming(fetched from a datastore) and the object was big in size. When multiple threads started calling the method, we were creating such big objects(twice too) per method call and soon our servers died with OOM. Moving to option 1 would increase the performance but I am wondering if it would make the memory utilization worse.

Comment: your question is too simplicistic to represent a complex production environment. it's best to just try and measure the difference instead of speculating what might happen.